# Show appsettings.json value in cshtml file in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to show value from the `appsettings.json` in a `.cshtml` file in ASP.NET Core 3.1 as we do in ASP.NET MVC like below:

```
@(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionExpire"])
```

Can you help how to implement this in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC ?

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation about [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)? Is there part of the documentation you need help understanding?

Comment: It depends on  many factors.  If  you need some help you have to show the code you have done so far. the view   where are you going to display   and a controller with action where  you are creating  the view model.

Comment: Be careful. The `appsettings.json` usually contains sensitive information, which should not be printed in a webpage or api response. It's a really bad idea...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a demo to show value from appsettings.json in view:

appsettings.json:

```
{
  ...
  "Test": {
    "TestValue": "testValue"

  }
}
```

view:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
@Configuration.GetSection("Test")["TestValue"]
```

Comment: I tried this with my appsetting value defined in azure app service ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString and trying to refer that in my layout.cshtml like cfg: {
                connectionString: @Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights")["ConnectionString"]
            } But this does not work and when I replace this with hardcoded value it does. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Yiyi You's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151666/8816314) is appropriate for when your value is under a section. But if your value is directly under the root of `appsettings.json`, for example:

```
{
    ...
    "MyValueAtRoot" : "value"
}
```

Then you need to call it from your view using:

```
@Configuration.GetValue(typeof(string), "MyValueAtRoot")
```

An additional interesting fact: The `GetValue` method has a generic overload method, but the returned value of such methods can't be rendered directly as html because the generic type parameter gets confused with plain html.

If you really want to use that method, you would first have to store the returned value in a variable, inside a razor code block, like this:

```
@{ var myValue = Configuration.GetValue<string>("MyValueAtRoot"); }
```

Then later render the variable:

```html
<p>@myValue</p>
```

Note: *For both of my examples, you also need the call the `@using` and `@inject` directives first, as described in the accepted answer.*